# WAMP server not working and giving some error related .dll file

Tags: php

I am using wampserver 2.5.  After installation, when we start it, it produces the  error

> The procedure entry point php_win_err could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dll

I also changed the port because some other application uses this port.

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/PHP/Q_24905799.html

Answer (score 0):

The MSVCR100.dll file is part of the Microsoft Visual C++, redistributables.

```
For Windows 32 : Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package x86 : VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe
```

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328

```
For Windows 64 : Be sure that you have installed the Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package x64 : VC10 SP1 vcredist_x64.exe
```

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13523

Apche wont be able to run without this component

Comment: I am already install this file but still it give me error as we discused above.